# Book about uploaded humans in dystopian future, digital world starts getting shut down

Tags: story-identification, books

I think this book is of fairly recent vintage (2009+).

It involves a dystopian real world burdened by overpopulation. Science has developed a Matrix-like digital world where human consciousnesses are uploaded to an idyllic environment, at least for the people with enough cash.

Almost everyone who can afford it is in this new silicon environment. Then someone starts turning off portions of the new digital world. The protagonist is the lucky one to get re-sleeved (to use Morgan's apt phrase) and goes unwillingly back into meat-space to find the perpetrators.

Comment: The Otherland series contains a VR breaking down kinda like you describe, but the protagonist doesnt match at all. Any other details that could help?

Comment: Not a match, but reminds me of 'The Machine Stops':
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops

Read this one today and remember it was written in 1928........